# Drupal Exporting large data using cron

Tags: csv, drupal-7, cron, export

I am working on a website which has around 150k users. I have to create a csv file which contains the details of user (drupal fields and profile2 fields ) and export the csv to another server daily.

I have implemented by export function in a hook_cron and in the function i do a user_load function call and two profile2_load_by_user and some other custom mysql queries.

The problem which i have is that my export_function does not seem to terminate, it may be a timeout or a memory problem.

I have tested my function my limiting the number of users to around 1000 and it works fine.

I am wondering whether it is possible to export huge volume of data through hook_cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inspect your server's error log in order to find out if it really is a memory or timeout problem. You could then fine tune your php.ini to reflect your requirements. Please keep in mind that `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` are there for a reason, and you should investigate the impact on your server when modifying those settings.

A more secure solution would maybe be exporting your users data in chunks over a number of cron cycles.

You might also want to check the [Views data export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module as an alternative to export your data.